# Python Regex Match for every single character in a "alphanumeric word"

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So I've this alpha-numeric word "DA7L1234AAAA" and I'm trying to match each character in that using Regex and have been largely unsuccessful. Below is my python script and bit more of explanation on the word,

```
DA7LD11234AAAA
D - It can be either one of D or T or U or P
A - alpha-numeric
7 - alpha-numeric
L - alpha-numeric
D - letter
1 - Number
1 - Number
2 - Number
3 - Number
4 - Number
A - letter
A - Letter
A - Letter
A - letter
```

---

```
import re
import os
import shutil
import os.path

var = "DA7L1234AAAA"
regex = re.compile("[dtup]\w{1}\w{1}\w{1}\w{1}\w{1}\d{1}\d{1}\d{1}\d{1}\[a-zA-Z]\[a-zA-Z]\[a-zA-Z]\[a-zA-Z]",re.IGNORECASE)
if (regex.match(var)):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Please help. I'm a noob for regex and python

Comment: `DA7LD11234AAAA` in description, `DA7L1234AAAA` in the code does not match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex that follows your description list:

```
(?i)[dptu][a-z0-9]{3}[a-z][0-9]{5}[a-z]{4}
```

`(?i)` is a modifier to make the pattern case insensitive